# Dots and arrows in a graph

Tags: tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

Please, I'm looking help to represent this graph.

[image]

I don't understand why the arrows doesn't appear, and also I'll have problems to represent the dots.

My try:

```
    \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) at (0,2) {$V_a$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (B) at (2.5,2) {$V_b$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (C) at (5,2) {$V_c$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (D) at (7.5,2) {$V_d$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E0) at (-2,0) {$e_0$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E1) at (0,0) {$e_1$} ;
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E2) at (2,0) {$e_2$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E3) at (4,0) {$e_3$} ;
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E4) at (6,0) {$e_4$};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E5) at (8,0) {$e_5$} ;
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (E6) at (10,0) {$e_6$} ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
\path [->] (A) edge node[left] (B);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

So, please, support me with an orientative example (I don't find nothing similar).

Thank you!

Comment: Replace `\path [->] (A) edge node[left] (B);` by `\path [->] (A) edge (B);`, then the arrow is drawn.

Comment: To draw dotted line, you can use, for example `\path[dotted, draw] (E5) edge (E6);`.